# Android connectivity with Desktop app

Tags: android

Currently i am building a mobile app on ubuntu 11.10 system.For checking the local app on phone i am using emulator.Is it possible to check the local app through my android phone.via emulator i am accessing my app via 10.0.2.2:3000.For android mobile how to do

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: What to check my local application on my android phone

Answer (score 0):

Read up on [Using Hardware Devices](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html) in the android dev guide.

You'll need to enable ADB on your device also, then plug it in with USB. Depending on your device you might have to find some ADB drivers for it.